# Search all columns as a single text per row

Tags: postgresql

Like google-search or any other search-box, search "all columns as single text" is a simple and universal tool, but I not seet how to do it using `tsquery`/`tsvector` tools.

No problem if it is an extension: I need an extension that offers a full-text-search with a kind of `contains(*,text)` (the same `*` of `SELECT *`) instead to concatenate each column-value.

> There are times when a formal structured query language is overkill, and the easiest way to find the right content is to perform a search, like you would with a search engine such as Google or Yahoo (...) JCR-SQL2:
> `SELECT * FROM [nt:base] WHERE CONTAINS([nt:base],'full-text-query')`
>
> [Full+text+search example in other SQL engine](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE50/Full+text+search)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can cast the complete row to a string (text) and then use the built-in [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) on that result:

```
select *
from foo
where to_tsvector(foo::text) @@ to_tsquery('full-text-query');
```

`foo::text` concatenates all columns of that table as a single large string, using the default text representation for non-text data.

Comment: This is a neat trick, but the problem is that it is hard to index, as foo::text is not immutable.  What I did in a similar situation is create a pl/perl function which returns the concatenation of all column values (minus a couple which it made not sense to search) with a suitable delimiter and falsely mark it as immutable, then index the results of that function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no extension. That's not how SQL works. There is no "grep on a table". You can however, use the `information_schema` to generate a dynamic query for this. First we create a sample table,

```
CREATE TABLE foo (a text, b text, c text, d text);
```

Now we have a query,

```
WITH dest(catname, schemaname, tablename) AS (
  SELECT CURRENT_CATALOG::text, 'public'::text, 'foo'::text
)
SELECT
  FORMAT (
    $$ SELECT * FROM %I.%I.%I WHERE %s$$,
    dest.catname,
    dest.schemaname,
    dest.tablename,
    string_agg(
      FORMAT(
        $$to_tsvector(%I.%I.%I.%I) @@ to_tsquery('rat & fat')$$,
        table_catalog,
        table_schema,
        table_name,
        column_name
      ),
      ' OR '
    )
  )
FROM information_schema.columns
CROSS JOIN dest
WHERE table_catalog = dest.catname
  AND table_schema = dest.schemaname
  AND table_name = dest.tablename
GROUP BY dest.catname, dest.schemaname, dest.tablename;
```

Now you can run that in psql with `\gexec`, or `EXECUTE` is as dynamic sql.

```
INSERT INTO foo (a,c) VALUES ('HALLO', 'FAT RAT');
(paste query above)
\gexec
```

You can also write dynamic sql to concatenate each field, if that's what you want and you're just being lazy by not wanting to write it out.

Comment: PS: today a RDBMS as PostgreSQL  can't say "that's not how SQL works"... We have XPath, [JSONb algebra](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html), etc. to work with other representations, to be friendly and competitive (!).

Comment: For `to_tsvector/to_tsquery` your solution lost this aspect, is complex, and slower than the "cool trick". But your solution is a good reference (!) to express any other alternative demand, when default text representation (for non-text data) is not adequate.